# MS Word removes access to file content on Android 11

Tags: android, ms-word, android-storage, scoped-storage

My app uses **Scoped Storage**:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

I save a file to

```
MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
```

then I create an edit intent:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

            setDataAndType(uri, mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension))
        }
```

On Android 11 if I edit this file with **MS Word** after that my app has no more access to that file:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.myapp.debug has no access to content://media/external_primary/downloads/5414
```

on Android 10 works fine.

Another app, for example, WPS Office works fine on both 10 and 11.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: If I had to guess, Word is removing the existing file and creating a new one in its place. You will not have access to that new one via the `Uri` that you used to create the original one.

Comment: @CommonsWare so the only option is to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? As MS Word doesn't work with ContentProviders (https://github.com/cryptomator/android/issues/150#issuecomment-514401775)?

Comment: The issue that you linked to indicates that MS Office does support some `FileProvider`-based `Uri` values. Perhaps try that.

Comment: When I do so MS Word can open it in edit mode but when I try to save changes it requires to save it as a copy. Looks like there's no solution.

Comment: In the end, IMHO, Microsoft needs to do a better job handling this scenario. There is very little that we can do about that, other than hope.